# Why does this array of characters contain memory that is not populated?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

I have an array of characters that consists of 5 spaces. I am trying to fill it with characters using a for loop. However, the array contains several spaces full of garbage when the loop is finished. In this example, it should produce an array that results as `'aaaaa'`, but it instead comes out looking something like `'aaaaaýýýý««««««««þîþîþ'`. Why does this occur? How do I prevent the unused memory spaces from being included in the array?

```
char* array = new char[5];

for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
{
    array[j] = 'a';
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add a `\0` at the end.

Comment: *You forgot to add a \0 at the end.*  And enough array elements to contain that NUL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The array doesn't contain anything other than the 5 `a` characters you've put into it. [Proof](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/435d2b3e4c9365fe):

```
char* array = new char[5];

for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
{
    array[j] = 'a';
}

for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
{
    std::cout << array[j];
}
```

However, my guess is that you were actually viewing the array value using an output like a string (or perhaps inside a debugger). Something like this:

```
std::cout << array;
```

In this case, the `char*` is treated as a *NUL-terminated string.* Which means it expects that all characters until a NUL-character are part of the string. Since your array doesn't have one, it's just outputting random memory following your array, until a NUL character is encountered.

If you want to treat your array like a string, you need extra space for the NUL terminator:

```
char* array = new char[6];

for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
{
    array[j] = 'a';
}
array[5] = 0;
```

However, if you actually want a string, you should use `std::string` and not `char *`. C++ is not C.

Answer (score 2):

Your array actually **is** "aaaaa", however it contains no terminating zero byte (ASCII NUL character), so the *character string* extends over whatever happens to reside in the memory just beyond the array's end.